# Prove that if $nm ≤ nx < nm + n $, where $ n,m ∈ ℤ $ and $ x ∈ ℝ$, then there exists ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Prove that if $nm ≤ nx < nm + n $, where $ n,m ∈ ℤ $ and $ x ∈ ℝ$, then there exists $j$ such that $j ∈ ℤ$ and $0≤ j <n$ for which $ nm+j≤ nx <nm+j+1 $.

I'm trying to prove Hermite's identity, which states that [image] for every real number $x$, and every positive integer $n$.

Part of the proof states what is underlined in red:

[image]

I don't understand why that is true; I've tried to prove it, but have failed to do so. Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: What did you try? What do you know about the floor function? Have you tried particular cases? Do you understand what is happening, but do not see how to make it rigorous, or do not have an intuitive understanding yet?

Answer (score -1):

Let $ j = [nx] - nm$ and then the magic happens. Think that the inequality is a fancy way to find the remainder of the floor modulo $n$.

Your inequalities still hold when applying floor, so $nm \leq [nx] < nm + n$. But, by definition, $[nx] = nm + j$ (such $j$ must exist because of $[nx]$ bounds) and you'll get $[nx] = mn + j \leq [nx] < mn + j + 1 = [nx]+1$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain?